# sql with rank and pivot - need rank within each partition and total rank in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, partitioning, rank

I can't seem to get this correctly. I need the customer's rank based on highest sum of rev_amount on the total group and then rank by sum of revenue for each entry in bu_list - is this possible? The reason i want this in one query is because i have made a sample value list below but my actual table has 20,000 customers and about 25 bu_id's so i really something simple. I have been fiddling with rank and pivot in one query but cannot seem to get it right. Thanks for the help.

```
CREATE TABLE bu_list ( bu_id int, bu_name varchar(50) );
CREATE TABLE cust_list ( cust_id int, rev_amount int, bu_id_fk int );

INSERT INTO bu_list VALUES (1, 'East');
INSERT INTO bu_list VALUES (2, 'West');
INSERT INTO bu_list VALUES (3, 'North');
INSERT INTO bu_list VALUES (4, 'South');

INSERT INTO cust_list VALUES (1, 1000, 1);
INSERT INTO cust_list VALUES (2, 2000, 1);
INSERT INTO cust_list VALUES  (3, 2000, 2);
INSERT INTO cust_list VALUES  (4, 2000, 3);
INSERT INTO cust_list VALUES  (5, 4000, 3);
INSERT INTO cust_list VALUES  (5, 100, 3);
INSERT INTO cust_list VALUES  (6, 5000, 4);
INSERT INTO cust_list VALUES  (7, 6000, 4);
```

Expected output is

```
cust_id |total_rank| east_rank| west_rank| north_rank| south_rank
7         1                                                1
6         2                                                2
5         3                                  1
4         4                                  2
3         4                         1
2         4              1
1         5              2
```

Comment: Do you know the values in `bu_list` in advance?  If not, google "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    cust_id,
    total_rank,
    east_rank   = MAX(CASE WHEN b.bu_id = 1 THEN t.bu_rank END),
    west_rank   = MAX(CASE WHEN b.bu_id = 2 THEN t.bu_rank END),
    north_rank  = MAX(CASE WHEN b.bu_id = 3 THEN t.bu_rank END),
    south_rank  = MAX(CASE WHEN b.bu_id = 4 THEN t.bu_rank END)
FROM (
    SELECT
        cust_id,
        bu_id_fk,
        total_rank  = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY rev_amount DESC),
        bu_rank     = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY bu_id_fk ORDER BY rev_amount DESC)
    FROM cust_list
) t
INNER JOIN bu_list b
    ON b.bu_id = t.bu_id_fk
GROUP BY t.cust_id, t.total_rank
ORDER BY t.total_rank
```